# How to decode JSON in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a JSON object which I encoded in Python. I don't know if I am doing the encoding right or not.

```
  proc = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', 
                             '-p', 
                             password, 
                             'rsync', 
                             '-avz', 
                             '--info=progress2', 
                             source12, 
                             destination], 


                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
progress = json.dumps(proc)
return HttpResponse(progress, mimetype="application/json")
```

I want to use the object 'progress' in the JAVASCRIPT to show the progress bar in the Django template. How it can be done? Thanks

I am trying to implement it in a Django template like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function popUp() {
var jsProgress = JSON.parse(progress)
document.write(jsProgress)
}
</script>
```

But this shows nothing.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clearly what you're doing? In particular, how are you sending the JSON to the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can decode any string(don't care about mime type) with JSON.parse("string") https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

So just pass response from server to this method like that:

```
var jsObject = JSON.parse(server.response);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. See my edited question. How it can be done in my case?

Comment: Tried: var message = JSON.parse(progress)
document.write(message) but didn't work.

Comment: parese returns javascript object - it means that progress must be string which will be converted to message object. You can do: document.write(progress) if it's string, but not message